# Raw string commands that provides attributes to text when parsed?

Tags: swift

I would like to know if Swift has any raw string commands that allows you to give text attributes when it is parsed into Swift.

For example, /n is new line. Is there any other commands like those? Thanks!

Comment: `/n` is not a new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the "Special Characters in String Literals" section of [Strings and Characters](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html), which is part of the Swift language guide. Specifically:

> String literals can include the following special characters:
>
> - The escaped special characters \0 (null character), \\ (backslash),
>   \t (horizontal tab), \n (line feed), \r (carriage return), " (double
>   quotation mark) and ' (single quotation mark)
> - An arbitrary Unicode
>   scalar value, written as \u{n}, where n is a 1–8 digit hexadecimal
>   number (Unicode is discussed in Unicode below)

And welcome to Stack Overflow! Glad to have you.